Definite matching in Java pattern matching
I have some doubts about certain parts of the definite matching in the Java language specification.
For example, in 6.3.1.1:

Conditional-And Operator && The following rules apply to a conditional-and expression a && b (§15.23):
• A pattern variable introduced by a when true is definitely matched
at b.
• A pattern variable is introduced by a && b when true iff either
(i) it is introduced by a when true or (ii) it is introduced by b
when true.
It should be noted that there is no rule for introducing a pattern
variable by a && b when false. This is because it cannot be
determined at compile time which operand will evaluate to false.

I don't understand why the reason for "there is no rule for introducing a pattern variable by a && b when false." is "it cannot be determined at compile time which operand will evaluate to false.".
If there is
a instanceof String s

then the pattern variable  s  is introduced by this expression only when the value of this expression is  true .
So we can say "the pattern variable s is introduced by the expression a instanceof String s when true".
Whether it is "when true" or "when false", they both seem to be just writings generated by predicting the value of an expression.(Or rather, they take the value of the expression into consideration.)
I think this is completely different from "when true" or "when false" that appear in definite assignment.
For example:
{
 int k;
 int n = 5;
 if (n > 2)
 k = 3;
 System.out.println(k); /* k is not "definitely assigned"
 before this statement */
}

16.2.7:

The following rules apply to a statement if (e) S :
• V is [un]assigned after if (e) S iff V is [un]assigned after S and V
is [un]assigned after e when false.

I think if "when false" here is the same as that in definite matching, then k will be definitely assigned here.
So I think definite assignment doesn't take into account the value of an expression (except for some expressions with compile-time constants), (just as the specification states),(just as in this example), but definite matching obviously considers the value of the expression(Just as in the previous example).
In that case, I think I should be able to add the following after 6.3.1.1:
A pattern variable is introduced by a && b when false iff either
(i) it is introduced by a when false or (ii) it is introduced by a
when true or (iii)it is introduced by b when a is true.
I think there's nothing wrong with it, because I'm just considering the values of these expressions and writing down the predicted situations.This has nothing to do with the values at compile time.
However, the footnote is completely different from my view and has written down the reasons that I don't understand at all.
So I'm here to ask for help. Thank you for your reading and answering.

By your logic, given Object o, I should be allowed to write (o instanceof String s) && (o instanceof Integer i) ? s : s. Because s is a pattern variable introduced by o instanceof String s when true. Clearly, that's nonsense.

Whether a pattern variable is introduced is very different from definite assignment. The part you quoted from 16.2.7 is about if statements, not about &&.
Intuitively, there is no rule for "a pattern variable is introduced by a && b when false" because we cannot know at compile time which pattern is matched. Consider:
void f(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof String s && o instanceof Integer i) {
        
    } else {

    }
}

What pattern variable should be definitely matched in the else branch? No pattern variables should be introduced here, because if else is executed, that means o is not both a string and an integer. It could be a string, it could be an integer, it could be anything else. We have not gained any useful information about o in the else branch.
Let's look at section 6.3.2.2 of the spec. Pattern variables introduced by o instanceof String s && o instanceof Integer i when false will be definitely assigned in the else branch.  And according to your proposed addition to the spec, s is a pattern variable introduced by o instanceof String s && o instanceof Integer i when false, because s is a pattern variable introduced by o instanceof String s when true, so condition (ii) applies. This is obviously incorrect because the else can still be executed if o is not a String.
The same applies for any other pair of type patterns you want to match.
In fact, condition (iii) in your proposal is also not well-defined. "introduced by b when a is true" is not defined. There are only 3 forms as listed in the part just before the section header of 6.3.1:

introduced by some expression when true
introduced by some expression when false
introduced by some statement


You could say something like this instead:

A pattern variable V is introduced by a && b when false iff V is introduced by a when false and V is introduced by b when false.

which mirrors this rule for && for definite assignment (16.1.2):

V is [un]assigned after a && b when false iff V is [un]assigned after a when false and V is [un]assigned after b when false.

However, this is moot, because the same pattern variable cannot be introduced by two different expressions. But if it could, it would be a case like this:
// imagine if this works
if (!(o instanceof String v) && !(o instanceof Integer v)) {

} else {
    // 'v' could be introduced here, though its type would be something like Either<String, Integer>
    // Java's type system doesn't have that yet.
}


I've been reading your answer for a long time. Although I'm still thinking about it, it's been very helpful to me. Thank you. I still have a question now. Let's take 6.3.1.5 as an example, because the rules regarding  instanceof  are quite simple.

"A pattern variable is introduced by a instanceof p when true iff the pattern p contains a declaration of the pattern variable."Why can't I understand it as that whenever  p  contains a pattern variable, then  a instanceof p  will definitely introduce a pattern variable(Even though it's nonsense.)? Because there will always be a time when  a instanceof p  is "when true". Just like in the definite assignment example in my question, although  n = 5 < 2 , we still need to consider the situation when  n > 2  is false.And then draw the conclusion that k is not definitely assigned.

@user24723440 While there is "definitely matched", pattern variables are never "definitely introduced". We can never know for certain, at compile time. Even a pattern like a instanceof Object b will not match if a is null. We can only talk about "when true" and "when false". On the other hand, it is possible to determine at compile time which variables are definitely assigned.

Edit :Change n = 5 < 2to n = 5 > 2

@user24723440 I don't see how pattern matching is comparable to the definite assignment example of n and k.

Yes, you're right. I think I understand what you mean.

pattern variable was introduced in Java 16.
for example:
if (obj instanceof Type var) {
// The variable 'var' is bound to 'obj' if it is an instance of 'Type'
}

the line "there is no rule for introducing a pattern variable by a && b when false"
consider example below:
if ((a instanceof String s) && (b instanceof String s)) {
}

this will cause a conflict at compile time, because

If both a and b are instances of String, then s would be introduced twice, which is illegal because it leads to ambiguity in the code.
If the entire expression evaluates to false, the pattern variable s cannot be introduced in both a and b at once because the compiler doesn't know which side is responsible for the false evaluation.

